# iterate in numpy array over rows just in column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I want to iterate over a column in a numpy array (interpol_values_array) but only in that specific column to find the place where a value (mole percentage) to put.

```
column = interpol_values_array[:][-2]
for column in interpol_values_array:
    place = []
    place_array = np.array(place)
    place_array = np.searchsorted([interpol_values_array], mole_percentage,               
    side="right")
```

place_array should return me the index, where to put my value (mole_percentage)
Is that way a possible way? Further, is there a way using np.nditer, which could be a far more elegant?

Comment: Produce a mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Assuming `interpol_values_array` is a 2d array, to extract the last but one column use index `[:, -2]`. The double index you use works for selecting individual elements, not entire columns (it will select the last but one row in your case). In any case it's a bad habit.